# A question about linear independence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Dear friends I wanted to ask if $\operatorname{span}\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\}$ is contained in
$\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ and both $u_i$'s and $v_i$'s are linearly independent vectors in the vector space $V$, can we say both spans are equal?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.  Span($u_1,\ldots, u_n$) is a subspace $A$ of $V$, and Span($v_1,\ldots,v_n$) is a subspace $B$ of $V$.  Your conditions imply that $A\subseteq B$, and that $dim(A)=n=dim(B)$.  Hence they are equal.

A quick proof of this: If $A\neq B$, then there is some $x\in B\setminus A$.  We must have $x\notin Span(u_1,\ldots, u_n)$.  But then $C=Span(u_1,\ldots,u_n,x)$ would have higher dimension than $A$, and still $C\subseteq B$.